# Convert String into ASCII Byte Array then base64_encode

Tags: php, rest

I'm trying to convert a combined string into a ASCII Byte Array to pass it into a server as an http header. Been trying numerous ways like unpack, splitting strings and doing a loop to convert each. But the server I am passing the converted string still ignores it. Not so much of a support from the API I'm using so maybe anyone here can help if I'm doing anything wrong.

```
$billerId = '9999986379225246';
$authToken = '16dfe8d7-889b-4380-925f-9c2c6ea4d930';

$auth = $billerId . ':' . $authToken;

//this results in error
$auth_key_byte_array = unpack("H*",$auth);

//this also results in error
$auth_key_byte_array = hash_hmac("sha256", $auth, false);

//even tried a loop function
function create_byte_array($string){
    $array = array();
    foreach(str_split($string) as $char){
        array_push($array, sprintf("%02X", ord($char)));
    }
    return implode('', $array);
}

$auth_key_byte_array = create_byte_array($auth);
```